# Get change commands without modifying collection

Tags: algorithm, design-patterns, recursion, command-pattern

Probably a very poorly named title, but anyway...

I am using the command pattern on a hierarchical data set. So basically I need a method that returns an object that *describes* the changes that will be made without actually changing the data. So for example:

Object 1 -> Object 2 -> Object 3

If I move object 1, it will cause a change in Object 2, which will cause a change in Object 3 because they depend on each other. So...I need a method to recursively go through the hierarchical collection and gather up the changes that are required to move Object 1 without actually modifying the collection. Halfway through the recursion it would be nice to be able to use something like Object1.Location, but it may already slated for change so I can't reliably use it.

I feel like there are plenty of algorithms and such that need to do this type of "in place" modification. As a non-CS major I didn't learn much of this type of thing, so I don't really even know what search terms to look for to find a "solution". I put solution in quotes because I realize there probably isn't a direct solution for my problem, but I am merely looking for some good guidelines/examples of this being done to get my brain cranking.

Can anyone provide some real-world examples of this type of thing being done? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you explain what you need this for?

Comment: A project management application. The hierarchy is a bunch of tasks with relationships/dependencies. It needs undo/redo capability, so i need a list of changes to be able to undo a whole bunch of dependencies being auto-shifted.

Answer (score 0):

Well part of the solution might be the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). You can go through your object tree with the visitor and do something like generating a "cloned" tree representing what will be the result of what you want to do ...

Can you give us an example of what you want to achieve ?

my2c